# Unexpected result from mutiple asynchronous operations on each object in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, async.js

I'm relatively new to Node.js and still wrapping my head around callbacks and the asynchronous nature of Node.js. I've run into an issue that I just can't figure out; I've thoroughly searched the overflow and read through supporting docs, but still can't get it to work.

Essentially, the issue is that I have an array of objects and I would like to apply a number of asynchronous operations in sequence to each object. I've looked into Async.js and attempted various callback structures, but my compiler just keeps shouting at me.

My most recent version of the code is:

```
function processObjects(objects){

    console.log(objects);

    async.forEachOf(objects, function(object, key, callback){

        var imageProfile;
        var files = {};

        function readFile(callback){
            fm.mdfil("templates/no_object.jpg", function(result) {  // Read metadata from no_object.jpg template
                console.log("check1");
                files['name'] = object + "_" + timestamp + ".jpg"; // file.name = object.id + timestamp
                files['type'] = ".jpg";
                files['size'] = result.size;
                callback();
            });
        }

        function updateFileProfileAgain(result, callback){
            console.log("check2");
            var obj = [];
            obj.push(object);
            f.insF(req.user._id, files.name, "", "", files.type, files.size, "", "", "", timestamp, obj, function(result){  // Add record of the image to the Files Collection
                callback(null, result);
            });
        }

        function updateImageRef(result, callback){
            console.log("check3");
            o.updSO(object, "imageRef", imageProfile.insertedId, function(result){
                callback(null, result);
            });
        }

        function updateObjectImage(result, callback){
            console.log("check4");
            o.updSO(object, "objectImg", files.name, function(result){
                callback(null, result);
            });
            callback();
        }

        readFile(function(callback){
            updateFileProfileAgain(function(result, callback){
                updateObjectImage(function(result, callback){
                    updateImageRef(function(result, callback){
                        console.log(result);
                    });
                });
            });
        });

        readFile();
    },
    function(err, result){
        console.log("done");
    });
}
```

Timestamp is a global variable. Objects is an array with unique IDs. Essentially I want to parse all these unique IDs to give them their own image (in the readFile function), add a record of that image to a separate collection (updateFileProfileAgain), add a reference of the inserted record to the object's record (updateImageRef) and eventually add a string of the image record to the objectImg field per object (updateObjectImage).

The output of this code has varied from undefined callbacks (as functions) and undefined results. In some cases I did get result on the client, which would then show an updated record for one object, but not for the other (as if the files variable didn't update or it took the last known value), like so:

- Object [0] : imageRef: "594912a794c9dc8488292025"
- Object [1] : imageRef: "";

And the same for fields objectImg etc.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the result of each function to the next one.

Also, callbacks could be a headache. I recommend you to use `Promise chaining`.

```
Objects.forEach(function (object) {
  readFile(object)
    .then(function(file) { return updateFileProfileAgain(file) })
    .then(function(result) { return updateObjectImage(result) })
    .then(function(image) { return updateImageRef(image) });
});
```

With **ES6**

```
Objects.forEach((object) => {
  readFile(object)
    .then(file => updateFileProfileAgain(file))
    .then(result => updateObjectImage(result))
    .then(image => updateImageRef(image));
});
```

Comment: Hi Matías, thanks for your answer. I tried implementing promises, but my console tells me it can't read property of 'then'. Am I missing something obvious here?